# Remove 'accept: */*' (header) from curl commands generated by Swagger Editor?

Tags: openapi, swagger-editor

I'm using the online Swagger Editor. When I send a request using "try it out", it generates this curl command:

```bash
curl -X 'POST' \
  'https://coo.amazonaws.com/' \
  -H 'accept: */*' \   # Extra one 
  -H 'X-Amz-Target: send by me ' \
  -H 'Authorization: Bearer "token"' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application.1' \
  -d '{
  "AuthParameters": {
    "USERNAME": "John",
    "PASSWORD": "James"
  },
```

Remove`-H 'accept: */*'` from header in the curl command.